# Questions for Qt QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Hello, I have two questions about QML.

1. How can you disable window resizing? 
(for example, all my qml-s are 800x600 but when I enlarge the window you can see white space and I don't want to make it adaptive to every screen resolution, I just want to make my window's size fixed)

2. I'm using C++ to load qmls, but when I try to load more than one when some event happens (for example I need to load two qml's on mouse clicked) it just loads second qml.
So my question would be how to load multiple qmls from C++ at the same time?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The title is not in a [good format for this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should ask one question only per post. You can edit one of the questions out of here and post it as a second question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Foe instance, you can use `QQuickWindow` which is subtype of `QWindow` which has `setMinimumSize` and `setMaximumSize` methods.
2. We need more detailed explanation of your problem. It will be great if you will put it in separate post.

Answer (score 0):

(Question 2) I suppose you use the same loader for both files? If so, when you assign the second source, your loader forget about the first one and only load the second one. You need one loader per file.

You either have always the the instance of the loader or you can create them dynamically, so you could support any number of loaded files